# Coupled non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a sub-ode in a larger system that I am working with. It takes the form of

$$y' = a-b\frac{y}{x}$$
$$x'=c\frac{y}{x}-d$$

I've been looking around for solutions since I do not know of a general method for non-linear coupled ODEs. Does anyone have some intuition about the above system. It seems like there must exist a nice solution since $\frac{y}{x}$ appears in both equations.

Thanks!

Edit: This is under a known constraint that $x+y=C$

Edit 2: In the actual problem $b=c$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: notice that

$$y'+\frac{b}{c}x' = a-\frac{bd}{c} \implies bx+cy = (ac-bd)t+k$$

---

$\textbf{EDIT}$: With the edits we can simplify the equation to

$$x' = \frac{bC-(a+b)x}{x}$$

which is separable. It has a solution of

$$\frac{bC}{(a+b)^2}\log(bC-(a+b)x) + \frac{x}{a+b} = K-t$$

where $K$ is the constant of integration.

Comment: Sorry, not totally following? I don't see a quotient for y/x popping out of that?

Comment: By multiplying the system by a clever choice of constants and adding them the $\frac{y}{x}$ cancels and gives you an expression to plug back in to decouple the system.

Comment: Hmm, very clever. I'll have to think about how this actually works (I'm a statistician not a mathematician so apologies for being slow)

Comment: Okay so I did the algebra and saw the nice cancellation. I'm confused about the result though, that is an equation of a plane (or parabola) of solutions correct?

Comment: In the $xy$ plane, if you were to think of this as a movie, this is the equation of a line with a fixed slope that slowly just translates itself across the plane as $t$ increases. However, I haven't been able to carry the algebra further after plugging it in.

Comment: If it helps, I have a known constraint on x+y = C

Comment: In that case that makes $ac=bd$! That's exactly what I needed to get the algebra moving. Edit: Nevermind, we have something a little different. I'm still stuck.

Comment: Sorry one more update, in my actual problem b=c, I assumed a more general solution would have been easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

$$
(x+y)'=a-b\frac yx-c\frac yx-d = (a-d)+(b+c)\frac yx = 0\Rightarrow a-d = 0,\ \ \ b+c=0
$$

the the system to solve is

$$
\cases{x' = a - b\frac yx\\
y'= b\frac yx - a}
$$

NOTE

MATHEMATICA gives the result

$$
\cases{
x(t) = \frac{b c_1}{a+b}\left(W\left(\frac{e^{\left(\frac{c_2 (a+b)^2+t (a+b)^2-b c_1}{b c_1}\right)}}{b
   c_1}\right)+1\right)\\
y(t) = c_1-\frac{b c_1}{a+b}\left(W\left(\frac{e^{\left(\frac{c_2 (a+b)^2+t (a+b)^2-b c_1}{b c_1}\right)}}{b
   c_1}\right)+1\right)
}
$$

Here $W(\cdot)$ is the Lambert function.